# How to re execute the last command which name begins with letters not numbers?

Tags: linux, terminal

Re execute the last command which name begins with ‘c’.
I want to execute my history command detail which starts with c at last i.e the last command which start with c. First, i want to get that command and execute the command.

Comment: is that `!c` you are looking for? not sure I understand...

Comment: yea !-c this also works but fc -e- -7 executes the last command of seven place likewise i need of letter like fc -e- -c but it won't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read about the `CTLR-R` feature `bash` offers.

You type `CTRL-R` and a `c`, then the last command starting like that is suggested, shown and can be executed again. You can also modify it as if you just fully typed it.

The feature offers a "live search", so you can type additional prefix characters and thus limit the search result you get. Each repetition of `CTRL-R` suggests the *next* command in the shell history that matches the current search pattern.

Comment: fc -e- -7 i need like this

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last used commands that starts with letter c by running this command: `history | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep '^c'`.

If you directly want to run the last command that starts with 'c' (which I think is dangerous). You can run these commands or save as a bash script:

```
a=(`history | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep '^c'`)
num_cmds=${#a[@]}
last_cmd=${a[num_cmds-1]}
$last_cmd
```